# r - Join data frame coordinates by shapefile regions aka Join Attributes by Location

Tags: r, raster, shapefile, qgis

I have a large data set, loaded in R as a `data.frame`. It contains observations associated with coordinate points (lat/lon).

I also have a  shape file of North America.

In the empty column (`NA` filled) in my data frame, labelled `BCR`, I want to insert the region name which each coordinate falls into according to the `shapefile`.

I know how to do this is `QGIS` using the `Vector` > `Data Management Tools` > `Join Attributes by Location`

The shapefile can be downloaded by clicking [HERE](http://www.birdscanada.org/research/gislab/download/bcr_terrestrial_shape.zip).

My data, right now, looks like this (a sample):

```
LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   Year    EFF n   St  PJ  day BCR
50.406752   -104.613    2009    1   0   SK  90  2   NA
50.40678    -104.61256  2009    2   0   SK  120 3   NA
50.40678    -104.61256  2009    2   1   SK  136 2   NA
50.40678    -104.61256  2009    3   2   SK  149 4   NA
43.0026385  -79.2900467 2009    2   0   ON  112 3   NA
43.0026385  -79.2900467 2009    2   1   ON  122 3   NA
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   Year    EFF n   St  PJ  day BCR
50.406752   -104.613    2009    1   0   SK  90  2   Prairie Potholes
50.40678    -104.61256  2009    2   0   SK  120 3   Prairie Potholes
50.40678    -104.61256  2009    2   1   SK  136 2   Prairie Potholes
50.40678    -104.61256  2009    3   2   SK  149 4   Prairie Potholes
43.0026385  -79.2900467 2009    2   0   ON  112 3   Lower Great Lakes/St.Lawrence Plain
43.0026385  -79.2900467 2009    2   1   ON  122 3   Lower Great Lakes/St.Lawrence Plain
```

Notice the BCR column is now filled with the appropriate BCR region name.

My code so far is just importing and formatting the data and shapefile:

```
library(rgdal)
library(proj4)
library(sp)
library(raster)

# PFW data, full 2.5m observations
df = read.csv("MyData.csv")

# Clearning out empty coordinate data
pfw = df[(df$LATITUDE != 0) & (df$LONGITUDE != 0) & (!is.na(df$LATITUDE)) & (!is.na(df$LATITUDE)),]

# Creating a new column to be filled with associated Bird Conservation Regions
pfw["BCR"] = NA

# Making a duplicate data frame to conserve data
toSPDF = pfw

# Ensuring spatial formatting
#coordinates(toSPDF) = ~LATITUDE + LONGITUDE
SPDF <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(toSPDF[,c("LONGITUDE", "LATITUDE"),],
                                  toSPDF,
                                  proj4string = CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

# BCR shape file, no state borders
shp = shapefile("C:/Users/User1/Desktop/BCR/BCR_Terrestrial_master_International.shx")
spPoly = spTransform(shp, CRS("+init=epsg:4326 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))

# Check
isTRUE(proj4string(spPoly) == proj4string(SPDF))

# Trying to join attributes by location
  #try1 = point.in.polygon(spPoly, SPDF) # Sounds good doesn't work
  #a.data <- over(SPDF, spPoly[,"BCRNAME"]) # Error: cannot allocate vector of size 204.7 Mb
```

Comment: Instead of files you should provide a simple self-contained reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. How would you recommend doing so when a shapefile is involved? I felt that including a link to the file was the only way to accurately share what I was working with, especially since shapefiles are rather complex and not easily summarized in a small data frame. Thanks for your answer, but for example, I have no idea how `lux.shp` works or what it contains. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: In R you are dealing with a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. You can create one from scratch (e.g. `raster::spPolygons`) or by using data that come with R (e.g., `shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster"))`). The latter uses a shapefile of polygons, but the file format of the source is not that relevant.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to do a spatial query with points and polygons. That is to assign polygon attributes to the corresponding points. You can do that like this:

Example data

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
polygons <- vect(f)
points <- spatSample(v, 10)
```

Solution

```
e <- extract(polygons, points)

e
#   id.y ID_1       NAME_1 ID_2           NAME_2 AREA    POP
#1     1    3   Luxembourg    9 Esch-sur-Alzette  251 176820
#2     2    3   Luxembourg    9 Esch-sur-Alzette  251 176820
#3     3    2 Grevenmacher    6       Echternach  188  18899
#4     4    1     Diekirch    2         Diekirch  218  32543
#5     5    3   Luxembourg    9 Esch-sur-Alzette  251 176820
#6     6    1     Diekirch    4          Vianden   76   5163
#7     7    3   Luxembourg   11           Mersch  233  32112
#8     8    2 Grevenmacher    7           Remich  129  22366
#9     9    1     Diekirch    3          Redange  259  18664
#10   10    3   Luxembourg    9 Esch-sur-Alzette  251 176820
```

With the older spatial packages you can use `raster::extract` or `sp::over`.

Example data:

```
library(raster)
pols <- shapefile(system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster")) 
set.seed(20180121) 
pts <- data.frame(coordinates(spsample(pols, 5, 'random')), name=letters[1:5])
plot(pols); points(pts)
```

Solution:

```
e <- extract(pols, pts[, c('x', 'y')]) 
pts$BCR <- e$NAME_2 

pts
#         x        y name              BCR
#1 6.009390 49.98333    a            Wiltz
#2 5.766407 49.85188    b          Redange
#3 6.268405 49.62585    c       Luxembourg
#4 6.123015 49.56486    d       Luxembourg
#5 5.911638 49.53957    e Esch-sur-Alzette
```

Comment: `extract` was slow so I used `over`. Thanks.